# How do I get the length of my list in Haskell after creating it?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So using the filter function I created something that returns a list based on user-specified criteria. For example, `ispos x = x > 0` and you call that on the list using my function and it will return a list, but I want it to return the length of that list. How do I do that?

```
count'filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
count'filter p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x]
```

Comment: There is a builtin `length` function.

Comment: If you are required to implement this yourself without using builtin functions, I suggest you try to do an easier version by implementing `length xs` without the predicate.

Comment: a list is its own length, in unary.

Answer (score 2):

With [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length):

```
countfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countfilter p xs = length [ x | x <- xs, p x]
```

instead of the list comprehension, you can use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```
countfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countfilter p = length . filter p
```